# Reflection loop propertes inside a class

Tags: c#, class, reflection, member

I can't find a solution to my problem, so I try ask here. I have a class and I want to have a method in the class to test for the state of the Properties. The method should return true if any of the properties has more one or more values assigned. But i cannot find any examples of how to loop trough all the properties of the class itself with reflection and test if Count is > than 0.

Or should I use another technique than reflection?

I just want to avoid hard coding the Properties one more time in the Test method.

```
using System.Reflection;

public class cP
{
    public Guid gid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public List<string> p1 { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> p2 { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public bool HasDefinedValues()
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<int>))
            {
                string PName = property.Name;
                if (((List<int>)property.GetValue(property.Name, null)).Count > 0) { return true; };
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `property.GetValue(property.Name, null)` -- you need to pass the *class instance* which owns that property as the first parameter. If you're fetching the value of the `p1` property from the current class instance, pass `this`, i.e. `property.GetValue(this)`.

Comment: Also you are declaring `p1` and `p2` as `List<string>`, then you look for `List<int>`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just have a `List<List<string>>` defined that you can loop through instead?  It's best to avoid reflection if you can.

Comment: Thanks, canton7, it's working now 

Comment: Hi Cecilio, my mistake, the examples should of course be List<string> all the places 

Comment: Hi juhar, yes I need to use the p1 and p2 as properties where I use the class, so i think it might be confusing to hit the right value in a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is working now

```
using System.Reflection;

public class cP
{
    public Guid gid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public List<string> p1 { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> p2 { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public bool HasDefinedValues()
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<string>))
            {
                if (((List<string>)property.GetValue(this, null)).Count > 0) { return true; };
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).